# React native headerShown: false not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to have multiple options = I want headerShown to be false while also having params. However using both, it seems that the header will not go away. Here's my code.

```
<MainStack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
    >
        <MainStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}
                          options={[({ route }) =>
                                  ({title: route.params && route.params.data}),
                              {headerShown: false}]}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your login screen, you can mention

```
 React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      header: () => false,
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you know where I would place this? I tried putting it in my componentdidmount function and at the top level of my JS file, but it's saying navigation is undefined (and if I define it as this.props.navigation it throws an error). I know about react hooks, but I use the oldschool format because of my business partner.

Comment: Inside your login component, where we declare state and stuff